# Emailing a professor in another country for a feedback on a project that I'm working on?

Tags: etiquette, professorship, email

I am a telecommunication graduate (Bachelors holder) and currently getting my master degree"completed one semester" .

I am working on a project and developed a new  original idea and constructed multiple algorithms based on it, however my professors could not provide me with a feedback about this new idea since they are not specialists in the field of my work, So I need a feedback from a specialist.

How can send a decent email to professors in another country for getting an answer on whatever my idea is valid and can be published.

Comment: Use an apostrophe ' rather than a backtick ` in words like "I'm", "I've", "it's", etc. Backticks are used in Markdown for formatting snippets of text as code.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Are you currently a student? Are you asking about emailing professors at your own university, or somewhere else? Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: Related: [How do researchers send unsolicited emails asking for feedback on their work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/126623/14341)

Answer (score 4):

First, assuming that you are in the US, learn to use professional grammar, spelling, punctuation, capitalization, and fonts.  Starting off with "i m a" will not get any professor's attention.  Try using "I am a".

If English is not your primary language, and you must communicate in English, then find someone to help you.

Next, just write up what you need, in detail.  Spell it out, like this.

Dear Doctor ______,
I am a student in _________ and I am working on an idea regarding algorithms.  Specifically, ___________.

I would like to get your feedback as you are an expert in algorithms.  May I stop by your office during office hours?

Thanks in advance,
_________.

Comment: I see the question was edited and looks much better now.   If they are not local, then leave off the stop by the office part.  Maybe suggest a phone call.

Answer (score 1):

As i get from your question. The best approach is to compare your work with existing works. Read latest papers from reputable journals, related to your work. If there is some expert professor try to find his latest publications and see what direction is his work focused on.
Compare your algorithms with latest one in the same field say you are working on collision detection. So read whats the latest approach that has addresed the collission detection, remember collission detection and resolution are two different fields when you come to compare algorithms.

I dont think you should send your final work without publishing it to some one, as it is very easy that your hardwork may be stolen in such case.